# Using CursorLoader to get contacts causes duplication

Tags: android, cursor

I am building an activity which I want to populate with contacts that have telephone numbers.

I am not using an Intent because I want there to be a checkbox before each contact in my listview.

I am using CursorLoader. Here is some code from the onCreateLoader method;

```
String projection[] = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1" + 
    " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " =1";

    String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, selection, null, order);
```

I use a subclass of ResourceCursorAdapter with my ListView.

Does anyone have any ideas how I remove the duplicates? I don't want to use a Set unless I really have to.

Comment: Can you include your ResourceCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend querying the `Contacts` table as opposed to the raw `Data` table.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
```

The data table contains raw contact data, which can mean multiple entries for the same "person" since Android contacts are aggregated from multiple different account sources.  Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Thanks bro! that was exactly it! Something learned for today :)

Comment: what if the fields are not available in Contacts table? e.g. I need to get fetch Given Name and Family Name of all contacts, query from Contacts is not enough

Answer (score 1):

If you have already verified that the data returned by your cursor is not doubling results (and that content provider does not have duplicates), the problem is most likely in your implementation of `newView` and `bindView`.  Make sure that `newView` just returns a "blank" view, meaning no values for TextViews or ImageViews have been set.  Set those values in `bindView`.  Most likely `bindView` isn't correctly setting the values in your views.